"Failed to get the server's share list. Permission denied" when trying to access Windows PC from Ubuntu, with Samba
Ubuntu 24 to Win7
It does ping, but when I try to access it with smb://pcpapa, I get this error message: Failed to get the server's share list. Permission denied.
I have another computer with an older Ubuntu that connects to the Windows (win7) network perfectly, so it's not an error with the Windows computer.
I have Samba installed, and the computer connects with other Ubuntu computers. I tried the following solution, but it didn't worked:
https://www.especialistashosting.com/blog/2012/01/samba-fallo-al-obtener-la-lista-de-comparticion-del-servidor/
